# Траектория выстрела навесом, Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот в этой игре: [youtube.com/watch?v=FsBCBRQURi8&feature=youtu.be&t=40](http://youtube.com/watch?v=FsBCBRQURi8&feature=youtu.be&t=40) 
есть механика прицеливания как во всех похожих 2D играх, как на Unity ее реализовать? а то все мои попытки пока не удались.

Снаряд имеет 2 rigidbody: наконечник и древко стрелы, движение реализовал следующим образом:

```
void Update () {
        this.transform.position += this.transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: берем уравнение движения тела, брошенного под углом к горизонту и применяем, не?

Comment: Как ты пытался? Покажи. Интересно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне нужно узнать как нарисовать траекторию, чтоб она могла плавно двигатся вслед за движением пальца (ну драг как в Angry Birds)

Comment: ну так это и есть та самая формула. ....у тебя есть угол, у тебя есть вертикальная прямая (ось Y), от которой отсчитывается угол, формула..... или ты не знаешь как применить формулу в коде?.... берешь формулу... задаешь несколько значений X, заносишь их в список.... по заданному углу и списку X, вычисляешь Y и тоже заносишь в список...... дальше на основе списка координат рисуешь линию любыми средствами

Comment: @АлексейШиманский проще делать шаг по времени, а не по X

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, вы правы

Comment: http://www.eduspb.com/node/1669 ..... https://ido.tsu.ru/schools/physmat/data/res/virtlab/text/m2_1.html .... просто посмотри на формулы, почитай о них... вспомни школу и физику)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да блин, я ж сказал формула не проблема, а именно отрисовать, отобразить, показать линию, через linerenderer или своими объектами как лучше, как оптимизированнее, чтоб потом она плавно перемещалась за пальцем, как в видео

Comment: Тут зависит скорее от того, как ты планируешь будет выглядеть траектория. будут различаться точки или не будут к примеру..... лично я бы генерировал объекты с нужной текстурой и нужным размером и вообще нужными опциями, которые где-либо устанавливаются. Т.е. таким образом как бы гибче можно было бы настроить отображение (расстояние между, разнообразие точек, их размеры, анимацию, независимость, их количество и пр.)....

Comment: ..плавное перемещение - хз... у тебя что с `linerenderer`, что с любым другим выбором придется манипулировать списком координат точек..... каждый раз обновляя их (точек) координаты... если человек пальцем будет вазякать - то перемещение так или иначе получится плавным....если перетыкивать пальцем - то проще новую быстро нарисовать.......если даже при перетыкивании хочешь плавно перерисовывать, то можешь прочитать про [градиентный спуск](https://habrahabr.ru/post/332198/)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, именно вазякать, через IDragHandler, впринципе я понял, буду пробывать, спасибо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский напиши пожалуйста в ответ пример использования формулы, а то я все никак не пойму как ее применить в коде, формула вроде понятная, но есть это "но", отмечу правильным ответом, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здравствуйте! вот для вас примерно перевел формулу в код для юнити.
Достаточно кинуть скрипт на объект с компонентом LineRenderer и проверять.
Не забудьте засунуть материал для компонента LineRenderer, иначе ничего не увидите.

Код является наглядным примером, вам придется переписать, дабы он удовлетворял вашим требованиям.

```
[SerializeField]
LineRenderer lineRenderer;
[SerializeField]
int dotsCount = 10;
[SerializeField]
float speed = 10;
float gravity;

void Start () {
    gravity = Physics2D.gravity.y;
}

void Update() {
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = dotsCount;

        Vector3 mouseWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 direction = mouseWorldPos - Vector3.zero;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x); // радианы
        //float angleDeg = angle * Mathf.Rad2Deg;//градусы
        for(int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            float t = i * .1f;
            float x = t * speed * Mathf.Cos(angle);
            float y = t * speed * Mathf.Sin(angle) + gravity * t * t / 2;
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, pos);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: проще чем я думал, просто не знал как angle считается в Unity, спасибо

Comment: @Vyacheslav в данном примере angle выдвется в радианах, чтобы перевести их в градусы можно это значение умножить `gradus = angle * Mathf.Rad2Deg`. Это так, к слову

Answer (score 0):

Сам полёт предмета лучше сделать таким образом:

```
    public Rigidbody projecile;
public int speed = 100;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Rigidbody instantiatedProjectile = Instantiate (projecile, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        instantiatedProjectile.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0,1,speed));
        Physics.IgnoreCollision (instantiatedProjectile.GetComponent<Collider>(), transform.root.GetComponent<Collider>());
    }
}
    }
```

Полёт предмета будет более реалистичным.
velocity придаёт направление и силу полёта предмета. 2ым параметром Vector3(0,1,speed) как раз и есть направление вверх. (предмет будет лететь по дуговой траектории).
IgnoreColision необходим, что бы предмет не бился о тебя при старте полёта.