# Пушка и гаубица

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня 2 вопроса:

1. Есть у меня танк, из которого вылетает пуля. С помощью `Rigidbody.velocity`, `AddForce` она летит по прямой. Как мне сделать так, чтобы она полетела как "по дуге" по кругу в цель, чтобы летела не прямо, а долетела прямо вверх, потом опустилась в точку? 
   Артиллерия. Пытался сложить 2 вектора: `Vector3.forward` + `Vector3.up`, не выходит, летит по диагонали и не падает.

Вот код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Point : MonoBehaviour {

private Transform point;

public Rigidbody force;
public GameObject effect;
public Transform to;

void Start () {
    force.transform.position = transform.position;
}

void Update () {
    Vector3 dir = (to.transform.position - force.transform.position +      transform.up);
    force.AddForce (dir);
}
}
```

2. Есть турель, её пушка прицеливается на объект, который вошёл в радиус её зрения, как только подходит другой, она сразу начинает переключаться на него (это мне нужно убрать). Как сделать так, чтобы пушка нацелилась на тот объект, который вошёл в радиус её зрения, но не переключалась на другой до тех пор, пока не добьёт первый? Чтобы куча объектов к ней подходило, а она не переключалась на другой, пока не добьёт первый. Как уничтожит, сразу переходит у другому. И если тот объект, который был в радиусе её зрения (атакуемый), вышел с её поля зрения, она сразу начинает переключаться на другой.

Вот код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Tower : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform spawn;
public Rigidbody bullet;
public float delay = 0.5f;

private List<GameObject> target;
private GameObject unit;
private bool can_shoot = true;
private float shoot_timer = 0.0f;
private float distance;

void Attack() {
    target = new List<GameObject> ();
    target.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Unit"));
    foreach (GameObject t in target) {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, t.transform.position);
        if (distance < 25) {
            Vector3 dir = t.transform.position - transform.position;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), Time.deltaTime * 15.0f);
        }
    }
    Ray ray = new Ray (spawn.position, transform.forward);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Unit") {
            hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Unit> ().health -= 1.0f;
        }
    }
    Rigidbody go = (Rigidbody)Instantiate (bullet, spawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
    go.velocity = transform.forward * 16.0f;
    can_shoot = false;
}

void Update () {
    if (!can_shoot) {
        shoot_timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (shoot_timer >= delay) {
            shoot_timer = 0.0f;
            can_shoot = true;
        }
    }
    if (can_shoot) {
        Attack ();
    }
}
}
```

Жду ваших ответов.

Comment: Изучите школьный курс физики, а именно - "Движение тела, брошенного под углом к горизонту"

Comment: тут не принято задавать вопросы типа "N вопросов в одном". Тем не менее по второму вопросу ответ очень короткий: заведите логическое свойство `HasTarget` у вашей турели и меняйте его значение на истину, когда орудие захватило цель, и на ложь - если цель ушла или уничтожена. При обнаружении новой цели просто проверяете это свойство.

Comment: Как логикой швыряться, так все мастера. А как дело подходит к коду, так все в кусты.

Comment: если все написать за вас, то вы ни чему не научитесь. Если хотите писать игры и заниматься этим серьезно, то придется учиться, причем постоянно, независимо от возраста и опыта.

Comment: Вы же добавили сами поле can_shoot и проверяете его в коде? добавьте также HasTarget. Или этот код просто копипаста из другого источника?

Comment: Можешь написать код нубу. Я совсем тупой походу.

Comment: Умоляю, напиши. Мне безполезно объяснять.

Comment: То, что вы предлагаете с bool, не сработает.

Comment: Мне нужно понять, как можно сделать так, чтобы она стреляла только на один объект. Мне нужно взять один элемент из массива. Со стрельбой флаг проканает, с этим нет.

Comment: Для начала, все таки перенесите второй вопрос в отдельный топик., а тут оставьте только первый. Там и продолжим обсуждение.

Comment: `Можешь написать код нубу. Я совсем тупой походу..... Умоляю, напиши. Мне безполезно объяснять`  - я так понимаю и код выше тоже тебе кто-то написал? Тогда может пойти к нему?

Comment: @ArchDemon `Изучите школьный курс физики, а именно - "Движение тела, брошенного под углом к горизонту" ` - не поверишь... как-то тут уже даже было https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692505/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-unity3d#comment1023938_692505  ........ и даже ответ есть какой-то https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693478/191482 ))

Comment: Код выше я написал сам полностью.

Comment: Просто столкнулся с этой проблемой.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пушка поворачивалась на объект, находящийся в массиве до тех пор, пока он не будет уничтожен.

Comment: Я создал новую тему по второму вопросу, как вы и просили.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702352/Поворот-пушки-за-одним-объектом-до-тех-пор-пока-он-не-будет-уничтожен

Answer (score 0):

По 2ому вопросу. Раздели функцию атаки на поиск целей и конкретно атаку текущей. Ищешь цель. Нашел запомнил, проверяешь 3 условия цель не  null, цель жива и цель находится в радиусе атаки, если все условия выполнились то вызывает  атаку. Иначе снова ищем цель

Comment: Уажаемые форумчане. Я прошу вас больше не кидать меня логикой Прошу, напишите код. Я уже какую только логику не пробовал. Кодил, сколько угодно. Где в коде ошибка?

Comment: @General2001 может тогда сразу игру за тебя написать? А то что так мелко-то?

Comment: Я просто прошу вас помочь исправить ошибку в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему сам.
Вот код:

```
bool nav = true;
    if (nav == true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < target.Count; i++) {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, target [i].transform.position);
            if (distance < 25 && nav == true) {
                current = target [i];
                nav = false;
            }
        }
    }
    Vector3 dir = current.transform.position - transform.position;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (dir), Time.deltaTime * 15.0f);
```

Причина: когда раньше пытался реализовать такую логику, неправильно использовал логическую переменную.