# Поворот пушки за одним объектом, до тех пор пока он не будет уничтожен

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d, искусственный-интеллект

Есть турель, её пушка прицеливается на объект, который вошёл в радиус её зрения, как только подходит другой, она сразу начинает переключаться на него (это мне нужно убрать). Как сделать так, чтобы пушка нацелилась на тот объект, который вошёл в радиус её зрения, но не переключалась на другой до тех пор, пока не добьёт первый? Чтобы куча объектов к ней подходило, а она не переключалась на другой, пока не добьёт первый. Как уничтожит, сразу переходит у другому. И если тот объект, который был в радиусе её зрения (атакуемый), вышел с её поля зрения, она сразу начинает переключаться на другой.
Вот код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Tower : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform spawn;
public Rigidbody bullet;
public float delay = 0.5f;

private List<GameObject> target;
private GameObject unit;
private bool can_shoot = true;
private float shoot_timer = 0.0f;
private float distance;

void Attack() {
    target = new List<GameObject> ();
    target.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Unit"));
    foreach (GameObject t in target) {
         float distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, t.transform.position);
    if (distance < 25) {
        Vector3 dir = t.transform.position - transform.position;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), Time.deltaTime * 15.0f);
    }
}
Ray ray = new Ray (spawn.position, transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
    if (hit.collider.tag == "Unit") {
        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Unit> ().health -= 1.0f;
    }
}
Rigidbody go = (Rigidbody)Instantiate (bullet, spawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
go.velocity = transform.forward * 16.0f;
can_shoot = false;
}

void Update () {
    if (!can_shoot) {
    shoot_timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (shoot_timer >= delay) {
        shoot_timer = 0.0f;
        can_shoot = true;
    }
}
if (can_shoot) {
    Attack ();
}
}
}
```

Жду ваших ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему сам. Вот код:

```
bool nav = true;
if (nav == true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < target.Count; i++) {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, target [i].transform.position);
        if (distance < 25 && nav == true) {
            current = target [i];
            nav = false;
        }
    }
}
Vector3 dir = current.transform.position - transform.position;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (dir), Time.deltaTime * 15.0f);
```

Причина: когда раньше пытался реализовать такую логику, неправильно использовал логическую переменную.