# Как добавить key в середину cruve

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытаюсь сделать так чтобы объект двигался по траектории дуги. Для этого я создал Cruve в скрипте я пытаюсь добавить keyframe в середину кривой по оси X(как на картинке)
Как добавить этот keyframe в середину cruve по x и плавно изменять x?

[image: Вот, что я хочу]

```
    AnimationCurve curveY = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, transform.position.y, 0.5F, TargetObject.transform.position.y);
    AnimationCurve curveX = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, transform.position.x, 0.5F, TargetObject.transform.position.x);

    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.y", curveY);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curveX);
```

Comment: А зачем вам описывать анимацию в скрипте?

Comment: Я хочу сделать снаряд который будет лететь под дугой но прилетать на кординаты цели в которую был выпущен в момент выстрела

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю как сделать это через анимации. Мне кажется вам стоит использовать физику движка, вместо анимации + так можно будет обрабатывать коллизии. Попробуйте посмотреть вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692505/Траектория-выстрела-навесом-unity3d.

Comment: Пробывал не вышло :D. Но все равно спасибо !